# Hide or Populate dependent <select> in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML jQuery form and depending on user selection in a select box a second select is displayed. I can either use .show() to display a second previously hidden div or I can use .append() to populate a select that is empty.

To clarify, either I can show or hide html or a I can append and remove html inside a form. Is there an advantage to one over the other in consideration of page load time / good practice?

Is there possibly an alternative that is more favorable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.

Consider for example a `<select>` with ZIP codes that is shown as soon as you select a country from another `<select>` :

- If you have zip codes for all supported countries, it makes perfect sense to first fill a hidden `<select>` element whenever you select the country and then show it, and hide it when you unselect your country, because you'll always need to pick a value, no matter which country you select.
- If you have zip codes only for some countries, it makes more sense to me to just append the `<select>` element and remove it when you unselect your country, because you only need to pick a value for countries where a list of ZIP codes is available.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.show()` , `.hide()` to prevent creating , appending element to `DOM`

Answer (score 1):

I much more prefer only to hide/show.

Why? Because of 3 things:

1. It works only with one property, not with whole element - it's faster.
2. You can run into harder coding, of targeting where exactly the second select should be, the append() just insert it in the last place, but what if it will be an element in the MIDDLE of some bigger structure?
3. CSS. In my opinion, it is harder to manage CSS to two states "having an element and having not the element completely". If you have the element all the time here, its more simple to mantain the layout.... But... that is my personal opinion.